# End-to-End communication between two networks

Tags: router, end-to-end, iot

I studied your article (CoAP) in    https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7228.
we are developing Home automation Solution with IoT enabled devices.

```
I have following doubts to provide the seamlessly solution for Home Automation.

 1. I have some appliance with Wi-Fi enabled controllers
 2. These controllers are connected to One Standard Router (ex:- CISCO,TP-Link, D-Link). All appliance connected to one router through Wi-Fi.
 3. These appliance controlled through local handheld devices by using our proprietary protocol with in the Home network.
 
Now, we want to give a one feature like operate these appliance by using Handheld device from Remotely.
```

Internet is enabled to this Router & also register one domain name.
But our problem is how to send commands or data from remote devices through Internet to home appliances.

***Note:-***
1.I don’t want to develop or place controller between IoT devices &
Remote handheld devices.
2. Request is initiated by remote handheld device only.

I hope, any body can guide to me for better solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to programming, it is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Can you tell me, where can i post this question..

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not a programming question I would like to make some references that can help you with decisions:

- AllSeenAlliance AllJoyn Framework [SmartHome Working Group](https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/smarthome/overview). I think, it will guid you how to develop better solution.
- [HomeOS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/homeos/) by Microsoft Research